# How to use a special character as a math operator?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I'd like to use `\v{C}` as a math operator. However, if I write `$\v{C}_r(S)$` or define `\DeclareMathOperator{\Cech}{\v{C}}`, the `\v{C}` symbol does not get shown at all. What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: `\v` is a text accent, the math equivalent is named `\breve`

Comment: @daleif No: `\breve` is curved. The math equivalent is `\check`

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans my bad, had a meeting to go to, so it was a little fast

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\v(C)` only works outside maths mode. For inside maths mode, use `\check{C}`. Thus (providing you are using the `amsmath` or `mathtools` packages), create your operator using:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cech}{\check{C}}
```

and you can then do `$\Cech_r(S)$` to get what you want.

Comment: For completeness, you should mention that `\DeclareMathOperator` requires either the `amsmath` or `mathtools` packages.

Comment: Note that if this operator is intended for comparison between two elements, you should use ``\mathbin{\check{C}}``.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes fair point. I assume the OP was doing that, but for the benefit of those who come here by google, I've added that as a parenthetical comment.